# Workflow with per page permissions

Tags: 8, workflows

I am creating a site for a complex organization of authors, editors, and publishers. Basically, each author is responsible for 1-5 pages and can only create drafts of these pages. Similarly, editors can only edit and approve pages to which they are assigned. There are max 5 publishers who are tasked with editing, publishing, creating new pages and navigation items, and assigning authors and editors.

If we have about 50 authors and 50 editors, how do we set up permissions and workflow for this site on Drupal 8?

One solution is to have Workbench Access set up to work on Taxonomy where each page is tagged with an author term and an editor term. We would then have to set up one term for every user and two fields on each page. Is there a more direct approach?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Drupal Answers. It's really difficult to help you out with that I guess. I mean, sure there is one direct approach: Code the feature you need yourself ;) But I guess you are asking for some modules or settings that are probably documented somewhere else but not here on Drupal Answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Business Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/business_rules) module to check if the page has the is on the specific workflow state and if the user has the correct rule to view or edit it.

Comment: Can you provide more information on how to configure rules for individual users?